# How to declare an interface that works with lambda?

Tags: android, lambda, interface, kotlin

I declared a simple interface like this:

```
   interface OnSomethingReadyListener {
        fun onSomethingReady()
    }
```

And of course a setter:

```
private val onSomethingReadyListeners = ArrayList<OnSomethingReadyListener>()

fun addOnSomethingReadyListener(callback: OnSomethingReadyListener) {
    onSomethingReadyListeners.add(callback)
}
```

But then I found that I cannot use lambda:

```
something.addOnShopDataReadyListener { progressbar.visibility = View.GONE }
```

IDE gave me an error:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: SomeClass.OnSomethingReadyListener
Found:    () -> Unit
```

Suppose I want to stick to using lambda instead of anonymous class (`object : OnSomethingReadyListener {...}`). How should I declare `OnSomethingReadyListener`?

Comment: Your claim that it only happens when the method has no parameter, doesn't check out on my side. It doesn't work with or without parameter.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I am sorry, you are right. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAM (single abstract method) conversion is only support for Java interfaces, not Kotlin interfaces.

[The documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html) states this reasoning:

> Also note that this feature works only for Java interop; since Kotlin has proper function types, automatic conversion of functions into implementations of Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary and therefore unsupported.

[KT-7770 requests this functionality](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770), if you want to track whether it is being considered or not.

The recommended way to achieve what you want is to replace the `OnSomethingReadyListener` with a parameter of type `() -> Unit` like so:

```
private val onSomethingReadyListeners = ArrayList<() -> Unit>()

fun addOnSomethingReadyListener(callback: () -> Unit) {
    onSomethingReadyListeners.add(callback)
}
```

You can then invoke those listeners with something like

```
onSomethingReadyListeners.forEach { it.invoke() }
```

Comment: Thank you! Just one more question, if, for readability reason, I want to declare my own interface (e.g. with several named parameters, but one method only), is that I can no longer use lambda? I tried @LucaNicoletti 's answer but it does not work.

Comment: "SAM conversion" is the technical term for what you want: converting an interface type to an equivalent function type. This answer presents a quote from the authoritative source explaining that this feature is _not_ supported for Kotlin interfaces and is there only for convenience of interop with Java. In other words, the Kotlin team wants you to use function types.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the function as this:

```
fun addOnSomethingReadyListener(block: (OnSomethingReadyListener) -> Unit)
```

And then you can call it as follow:

```
addOnSomethingReadyListener {
  // TODO
}
```